# Is there a way I can get the Bar Width in px/dp's of an MP Android BarChart?

Tags: java, android, xamarin.android, mpandroidchart

I want to create a "table" (which is build with a recycle view) below my chart. But I want the RecycleView to have the same number of elements of my chart (In this case 7) Is there a way to get the column `width` of the `Bar Chart`so I can assign the same width to my Recycle View Cells?

[image]

**At the end (if it is posible) I want the two scroll to be synced.**

Answer (score 2):

The bar width in pixels is the difference between the value bar width x position (wp) and the label starting position (xp):

```
        Transformer transformer = bChart.getTransformer(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
        float bw = (float) transformer.getPixelForValues(bChart.getBarData().getBarWidth(), 0).x;
        float xp = (float) transformer.getPixelForValues(0, 0).x;
        float barWidthInPixels = bw - xp;
```